# Streaming Netflix on my CR-48

Tags: google-chrome, silverlight, video-streaming, netflix

I'm running Chrome OS on my [CR-48](http://www.google.com/chromeos/pilot-program-cr48.html). I know Chrome OS doesn't currently support Silverlight and thus doesn't support Netflix but I'd like to give it a shot anyway. What about playing it on my PC and remote accessing the PC to watch it? I currently use ThinVNC for remote access from Chrome OS but it doesn't have any audio support, plus the video refresh rate is pretty slow for watching video. I use Subsonic for media access from my CR-48 but I don't see anyway to get this to work with Netflix since Subsonic only works with files downloaded to my hard drive. Any way I could do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Readers of the future:  please note that Chrome OS supports Netflix natively these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use the Remote Desktop Connection feature built-in to Windows XP and later.  Remote Desktop supports remote audio and it's video subsystem works at higher level in the Windows operating system and will offer improved video quality, although it still might not be acceptable for video watching.

You can enable Remote Desktop in the System section of the Control Panel on Windows.  The only way to run `rdesktop` on Chrome OS seems to require [copying the binary from a Linux Live CD or USB](http://www.chromeoslounge.com/apps-extensions/271-rdp-client-chrome-os-2.html) but I don't have a CR-48 so someone who does might know of a better solution.

By the way, Silverlight does work on Linux (and thus could run on Chrome OS), via the Moonlight application from the Mono project, but Netflix currently doesn't allow their Instant Queue service to run on Linux clients.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I don't think I can use the RDC feature built into windows since I'm running just Chrome OS and not jail breaking to also run Linux. I have a feeling that some other remote access solution could work quite well though. I didn't think Silverlight and Moonlight were the same thing. And even if Netflix videos would theoretically run in Moonlight would it support the DRM they use?

Comment: @Blake:  There are a couple of ways to get better video performance out of VNC but no way to get audio that I'm aware of.  The link I provided explains how to copy `rdesktop` from a Linux installation but otherwise leave Chrome OS unmodified.  It's not "jailbreaking" by any stretch of the imagination.  I just had another idea I'll post in a different answer though.  The DRM is exactly the problem.  Netflix chooses not to support Linux, there is no technical limitation that prevents them from doing so.

Answer (score -1):

ThinVNC was rebranded to [Thinfinity Remote Desktop Workstation](https://www.cybelesoft.com/thinfinity/remote-desktop/workstation/). 
It now supports audio and has a smooth performance suitable for video streaming.

To enable the audio you need to launch the start page for Thinfinity Remote Desktop Workstation, and select "remote desktop" or "screen sharing" and hit "configure:

[image: start page view]

Then go to the "Resources" tab to enable the remote sound:

[image: resources - remote sound]

There's a 30-day trial, and you can register a free license here: https://www.cybelesoft.com/thinfinity/remote-desktop/workstation/free-license/

I work for Cybele Software. Feel free to let me know if you need any help with the settings/configuration.

Comment: Hi Mariana, welcome to Super User. As you did in another answer, could you **edit this answer** to disclose your affiliation please? Also have a read of the recommendations in [how to recommend software in an answer](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) for suggestions on how to make this seem less promotional- though I see you have already addressed OPs concern about audio. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! But this still comes across as somewhat promotional, as opposed to trying to answer a seven year old (!) question.  One of the aims of Super User (and the rest of the StackExchange network) is to build a library of answers which will be of use to future users with the same issue; as opposed to a forum where "Have you done *X*" and "Feel free to ask for help" back-and-forth may be more appropriate.

Comment: Bertieb, I tried to add pictures to make a complete response, following the instructions on the link you provided. However, as a new user I am not allowed to. Maybe I should just remove the link on my comment. Any suggestions?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the image uploader should give you links to the images; if you leave those in another user will edit that to show the images in the answer itself :)

Comment: Bertie, you are so kind! I added some further instructions. If you think I should make some editions, just let me know. Thanks again!